# Connection inout interface signal to pin

Tags: system-verilog

How do I connect an inout logic from an interface to a pin in the top level? The following is an basic example.

Interface:

```
interface SAMPLE_IF;
    logic signal; // inout
    modport master (inout signal);
    modport slave (inout signal);
endinterface
```

Top level file:

```
module top_level(
    inout pin,
);

SAMPLE_IF sample_if();

code_blk code_blk_i (
    .sample_if(sample_if)
);
```

In the example above, how does `pin` connect to `sample_if.signal`?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot connect an `inout` port to a variable; only nets/wires. If you change the interface signal to a wire, you can use a port expression:

```
interface SAMPLE_IF;
    wire signal; // inout
    modport master (inout signal);
    modport slave (inout signal);
endinterface
Top level file:

module top_level(
    inout .pin(sample_if.signal),
);

SAMPLE_IF sample_if();

code_blk code_blk_i (
    .sample_if(sample_if)
);
```

---

### Update

Apparently most tools do not accept that syntax. Here's a Verilog *alias* workaround.

```
interface SAMPLE_IF;
    wire signal; // inout
    modport master (inout signal);
    modport slave (inout signal);
endinterface

module top_level(
    inout pin
);

  Alias A (pin,sample_if.signal);
  
SAMPLE_IF sample_if();

endmodule 

module Alias #(P=1) (w,w);
  input  [P:1] w;
endmodule

module top;
   wire m;
   top_level dut(m);
endmodule
```